# Phantomjs. Webpage. Cant find element

Tags: automation, phantomjs, html

Following code is giving me null all the time. Although element exists and classname is correct. FindElementsByClassName is giving the same. What am I doing wrong?

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
    var page = webPage.create();
    page.open('https://www.google.com/', function(status) {
      var title = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelector('.hp vasq');
      });
      console.log(title);
      phantom.exit();
    });
```

Comment: `Although element exists and classname is correct` How do you know it exists? Have you checked it in the script?

Comment: I inspected element in browser.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your element has an `class` attribute with multiple classes, you can tell based on the value of the attribute, if this contains spaces then each separate word is a class.

example: `class="classA classB"`

In this case to select by class you have 2 options:

1) `[class='classA classB']`

2) `.classA.classB`

In your case the selector should look like this: `.hp.vasq`